# 7digital API : OAuth authentication error: Invalid signature

Tags: php, .net, api, oauth, 7digital

I have problems with the authentication, i am doing this steps:

**1. First time I get the oauth_signature by using this site url with following details:**
http://7digital.github.io/oauth-reference-page/

**url:** https://api.7digital.com/1.2/oauth/requesttoken

**consumer key:** MY_KEY

**consumer secret:** MY_SECRET_KEY

**nonce:** 814629426

****timestamp:** 1383291284

body encoding:** application/json

and them send request to get the oauth_token for the 7digital API:
https://api.7digital.com/1.2/oauth/requesttoken?oauth_consumer_key=MY_KEY&oauth_nonce=184615245&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1383144733&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_signature=sJ%2B%2BPq2i9LfC1xGG1EHx2DrTBxg%3D

This request gets the oauth_token and the oauth_token_secret.

**2. I need to authorize the oauth_token with the client key:**

https://account.7digital.com/7dysvzdxkkmf/oauth/authorise?oauth_token=7EP6KGD
The request responses  a page to registration or login if i have a 7digital account.

**3. I need to access token:**

https://api.7digital.com/1.2/oauth/accesstoken?oauth_token=JXLDXZY&oauth_consumer_key=MY_KEY&oauth_signature=uJ8jUSre5%2Fe5qiJsA5jeN54143M%3D&oauth_timestamp=1383204749&oauth_nonce=558206579

But on step 3 i got error message:
OAuth authentication error: Invalid signature.

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: Are you signing the access token call with you request token secret as well as consumer secret?

Comment: ya In step 3 i am exploring the query string to authorize the oauth_token(access) but it generate error message.

Comment: Kajal, could you try signing with our OAuth reference application here: http://7digital.github.io/oauth-reference-page/  This will remove the possibility that the client you are using has any issues.  As @MattGray says, in step 3 you should have the boxes "consumer key", "consumer secret", "token" and "token secret" filled in.

Comment: Have a look at the readme - there is a new step needed for running the sample/sdk tests. You will need to add some properties to the project gradle.properties file. There is a sample file (gradle.properties.sample) for reference.